# <f:setPropertyActionListener> works in one form, but not in another form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I found one problem to use `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{filialBean.tipoFilial}" value="0"/>`, I put this code in different forms, and put a debug point in the getters atribute in the bean class.

One form calls the debug mode in Eclipse, but the other form didn´t call, they share the same bean class.

So whats the problem?

Or anyone suggest other ways to pass value form a form? 
This value is hidden.

Comment: An SSCCE would help in understanding the problem. Perhaps there's just a conversion/validation error whose messages are never displayed? Perhaps there are some rendered/disabled attributes tied to a request scoped bean? Etc.

Comment: my atribute isn´t getting the value, but in the other form is getting...

they have the same code, to save

`
    <div align="center">
     <p:commandButton id="salvar" type="Submit" value="#{lbl['BOTAO.SALVAR']}" actionListener="#{filialBean.save}" update="messages">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{filialBean.tipoFilial}" value="0"/>
     </p:commandButton>
    </div>
`

Comment: @user2283439 Don't post code in comments, append the question with formatted code instead!

Comment: i changed  `actionListener` to `action` and worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *i changed `actionListener` to `action` and worked*

All action listeners are invoked in the sequence in the order they're declared on the component. The `actionListener` attribute is invoked *before* any `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`. If you have paid more careful attention to debugging (or *actually* debugged it instead of apparently lying) then you should have noticed that the setter **is** invoked, only at a later moment than the action listener method.

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/)